# Setar evento de click à um elemento que foi inserido via AJAX, depois do carregamento da página

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de busca instantânea com jQuery, Ajax e PHP. Criei um sistema de navegação pelas setas do teclado nas opções resultantes da busca. Está funcionando tranquilamente. Mas o que quero fazer é que quando o 'enter' for teclado em cima de uma dessas opções de busca, seja disparado um 'click' na opção selecionada. O problema é que estas opções são carregadas depois do carregamento da página. Então não consigo setar um clique da maneira tradicional com `.click()`, nesse elemento.

Tentei usar o

```
$(elementoPai).on('click', 'elementoFilho', function(){

});
```

Mas isso só atribui um callback para quando o `'elementoFilho'` for clicado. E não é isso que eu quero.
O que quero é setar! Clicar! nesse 'elementoFilho' teclando o enter.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você pode postar o código que faz a requisição Ajax?

Comment: Não percebi bem. Tens um exemplo de HTML? quando clicas no enter queres disparar um clique num elemento.

Answer (score 2):

`click` é com o mouse, `touch` com o dedo, `keydown` com o teclado... afinal você não pode clicar com o teclado ou digitar com o mouse.

```
$(elementoPai).on('click keydown', 'elementoFilho', function(event){
  if (event.type == "click" || event.which == 13) {
    // 13 -> Enter
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Vc tem que atrelar o elemento e o evento listern ao documento **document** DOM.
Tenta essa função abaixo, vai funcionar para qualquer elemento do DOM criado no futuro:

```
//Vc enqueceu de escolher o selector => elementoFilho é uma classe ou um ID?
//Se for id
$(document).on("click keydown", "#elementoFilho", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//Se quiser previnir o comportamento default. 
    //ponha seu cdigo aqui
}); 

//Se for class
$(document).on("click keydown", ".elementoFilho", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//Se quiser previnir o comportamento default. 
    //ponha seu cdigo aqui
});
```